# How to show a nicer error then :"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, security, asp.net-mvc

While doing some hacking on my own site I encountered (after some googling) a common problem.

"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client may it be a XSS attempt or a malicious character

case 1 : `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Firstname ="<script> alert("x");...").`

case 2 : `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (*).`"

The asp mvc team did a good job catching the error for me but how do I show a nicer error to my users. for example "Something happened, please repeat your steps, if this messegage appears again please contact person x ...".

Solution for asp MVC developers.

1. Create an ErrorController with a Index
2. Add the following line to your web.config :

> `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index"/>`

1. Write tests to check the controller operations.
2. Don't forget to create the actual view.

Optional you might want to put mode="RemoteOnly"

Note for more information on CustomErrors attributes : [customErrors Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)

Comment: It's not a MVC thing. WebForms does it as well. Both frameworks use the same code.

Comment: If you're using IIS7+ there's a simpler solution here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071341/asp-net-mvc-customerror-page-doesnt-get-displayed-for-some-of-the-400-errors/30072933#30072933

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not MVC-specific. ASP.Net webforms will give you the same error.

I think you should use Custom Error Pages. Custom error pages are defined in Web.config like:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx"/>
```

For more information about custom error pages, visit http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages

Also, you can handle Global.asax Application_Error event to do whatever you want.

Microsoft has a very nice article including source code which does exactly what you want to do (and more). check it out at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that is MVC specific:

- Create a custom FilterAttribute that implements IExceptionFilter
- from inside the FilterAttribute, you can redirect to the controller or view to be used to display the error.
- register the filter in the Global.asax or attribute your controllers

This has the advantage that you can show a different error page only for HttpRequestValidationException.

```
public class HttpRequestValidationExceptionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter {
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.Exception is HttpRequestValidationException) {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/HttpError/HttpRequestValidationError");
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```