# ASP.NET MVC customError page doesn't get displayed for some of the 400 errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having quite an interesting issue with the custom error pages management for a new ASP.NET MVC application.

This issue is like this:
- if I'm calling an URL (doesn't matter which) with a "bad" argument at the end of URL, like `..../c<`, the application is displaying the correct server error page as instructed in the web.config;
- if I'm changing the URL to a more nasty one, like `.../<c` (to look more like an HTML tag, there is no more server error page displayed in the browser and instead of that, I'm getting a plain YSOD with a message like `An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.`

According to ELMAH, both requests ended with a 400 status code and the message being:
- for the first one: `System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)`
- for the second one: `System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)`

So, both errors are the same, the status code is the same, but for one of the errors, the custom error page is not getting displayed. I've also went to global.asax in debug mode and checked the `Server.GetLastError()` in `protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` and again, both errors were the same, nothing is different.

In web.config, this is how my `<customErrors>` tag looks like:

`<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/ServerError.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="/ServerError.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/PageNotFound.aspx" />
    </customErrors>`

Can please someone tell me why the behavior is different in these two cases?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What are you hosting on? Cassini? IIS6? IIS7+?

Comment: IIS 8.5 (Windows 8.1) and also Azure Website.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a lot of misinformation and/or out-of-date solutions regarding error handling in IIS 7+. The main things to understand are:-

- .NET 4.0 made breaking changes to ASP.NET's request validation.
- IIS 7+ introduced a new way of handling custom error pages.

Most people are using hodge-podge solutions involving all of `customErrors`, `httpErrors` the `Application_Error` handler, and often setting `requestValidationMode="2.0"` on the `httpRuntime` property and/or disabling request validation entirely! This makes it really difficult to use other people's solutions because any and all of these can affect the behaviour. I had a quick search around and I found several semi-duplicates without accepted answers, probably for this reason.

The reason that these two errors give you different behaviour is that they occur at **different stages in the request pipeline**. The `customErrors` node in your `web.config` interacts with errors "*inside*" your application, while request validation takes place "*outside*" your application. IIS rejects the dangerous request *before* it gets to your application code, and so your `customErrors` replacement doesn't happen.

So how do we fix that?

Ideally you want a solution with as few moving parts as possible. IIS7 gives us a new way to specify error page replacement *at the IIS level* instead of at the application level - the `httpErrors` node. This lets us catch all our errors in one place:-

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <clear />
      <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/ServerError.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/ServerError.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/PageNotFound.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/ServerError.aspx" />
    </httpErrors>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
  ...
</configuration>
```

If you care about SEO (and you should!), you still have to make sure that your controller/page sets an appropriate status code:-

```
this.Response.StatusCode = 500; // etc.
```

You should remove your `customErrors` node entirely. It is normally used for backwards-compatibility. You should also ensure that `requestValidationMode` is *not* set on the `httpRuntime` node.

This should catch most errors (excluding, obviously, errors in parsing your web.config!)

Related:- [ASP.NET MVC Custom Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532039/asp-net-mvc-custom-errors/14578699#14578699)

MSDN Documentation:- http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors

Note: in your case, if you want to set `defaultPath` on the `httpErrors` node, you'll get a lock violation because of `ApplicationHost.config` settings. You can either do as I did and just set `path` individually for the error codes you care about, or you can have a look at unlocking the node:-

- http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig
- http://forums.iis.net/t/1159721.aspx

My intuition is that it's more trouble than it's worth in low-control environments like Azure App Service / Azure Web Sites. You might as well set the paths for individual status codes.

I've put a [full working example of using httpErrors for custom error pages up on github](https://github.com/iaingalloway/ASP.NET-HttpErrors-Example). You can also [see it live on azure web sites](http://httperrors-example.azurewebsites.net/Home).

Comment: By far this is the most detailed and perfect response that I've seen in years. Thank you very much!!! It's working perfectly!!!

Comment: I'm back with one more question: it seems that I have configured in my web.config a HttpModule (ImageProcessorModule) which intercepts all my calls (is quite normal) but when I'm dealing with the `A potentially dangerous Request.RawUrl value was detected from the client`, I see the error in clear text and no 500 custom error page shows up; though, if I'm commenting out this module to not intercept the requests, I see the custom error page... What am I missing? Why the system doesn't display the custom error message though the web.config says so?! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You might be best posting that as a separate question with more info. I'm aware of cases where bugs in httpModules have caused problems with custom errors, but I'd need more to go on before I could narrow it down.

Comment: I will do it in few minutes. Thank you!

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075396/http-module-intercept-requests-and-breaks-custom-errors-configuration

Comment: Awesome answer, if only all answers to problems where as good as this

Comment: @juFo: Post your problem as a new question and link to it here. Did you check out the github repository? Does the code there work for you?

Comment: I Always get A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<). instead of the normal page. I tried about everything :-)

Comment: @juFo: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a new question, link to it here and I'll take a look.

Comment: Explanatory and nice answer. Kudos!

Comment: @IainGalloway When implementing, if I include status code line `this.Response.StatusCode = 400; // etc.` the page causes infinite loop with every page load returning a 302 result. Any ideas on that? Both on Azure and local IIS (v10.0)

Comment: @mcy: Which versions of IIS and ASP.NET? Are you following the implementation in the linked github repo? You might want to ask that as a new question (and link here maybe).

Comment: @IainGalloway On close inspection, I found two differences between your example and my implementation. Correcting those made things work. Thanks again! (Note for future searches: differences were: 1. Error route mapping were not present. 2. error mode were `redirect` instead of `executeUrl`. 3. there were no `cref` tags in method definitions).